# Getting the album link from a list of albums with Facebook Graph

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The json below is the response I get from the server for requesting /id/albums, but I want to use that data to get the link to the album that has all the pictures in json format. The "link" field provided is to the actual desktop site, but I need the json. How would I use the json data provided (below) to send a request to graph.facebook.com to get the pictures within the corresponding album in json format?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "150228731810007",
      "from": {
        "name": "James McMahon",
        "id": "100004686423103"
      },
      "name": "Profile Pictures",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=150228731810007&id=100004686423103&aid=1073741831",
      "cover_photo": "150228735143340",
      "count": 2,
      "type": "profile",
      "created_time": "2013-03-15T05:29:24+0000",
      "updated_time": "2013-11-09T17:12:36+0000",
      "can_upload": false
    },
    {
      "id": "233767233456156",
      "from": {
        "name": "James McMahon",
        "id": "100004686423103"
      },
      "name": "Mobile Uploads",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=233767233456156&id=100004686423103&aid=1073741838",
      "type": "mobile",
      "created_time": "2013-11-09T17:12:30+0000",
      "updated_time": "2013-11-09T17:12:30+0000",
      "can_upload": false
    },
    {
      "id": "206255352874011",
      "from": {
        "name": "James McMahon",
        "id": "100004686423103"
      },
      "name": "Aug. 17th, 2013",
      "description": "Day with some of the Family",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=206255352874011&id=100004686423103&aid=1073741837",
      "cover_photo": "206255402874006",
      "count": 8,
      "type": "normal",
      "created_time": "2013-08-17T21:24:12+0000",
      "updated_time": "2013-08-17T21:24:36+0000",
      "can_upload": false,
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "1774907390",
            "name": "Ashley Carter"
          },
          {
            "id": "646440613",
            "name": "Mitzy Lanthier"
          },
          {
            "id": "1801948293",
            "name": "Calvin Carter"
          },
          {
            "id": "100000653918655",
            "name": "Kimberly Lane Lirette"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "after": "MTAwMDAwNjUzOTE4NjU1",
            "before": "MTc3NDkwNzM5MA=="
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "150230918476455",
      "from": {
        "name": "James McMahon",
        "id": "100004686423103"
      },
      "name": "Cover Photos",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=150230918476455&id=100004686423103&aid=1073741833",
      "cover_photo": "202581716574708",
      "count": 4,
      "type": "cover",
      "created_time": "2013-03-15T05:43:31+0000",
      "updated_time": "2013-08-08T17:26:35+0000",
      "can_upload": false
    },
    {
      "id": "158017154364498",
      "from": {
        "name": "James McMahon",
        "id": "100004686423103"
      },
      "name": "Timeline Photos",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=158017154364498&id=100004686423103&aid=1073741834",
      "cover_photo": "179650435534503",
      "count": 10,
      "type": "wall",
      "created_time": "2013-04-07T14:04:04+0000",
      "updated_time": "2013-06-12T23:28:45+0000",
      "can_upload": false
    },
    {
      "id": "178309025668644",
      "from": {
        "name": "James McMahon",
        "id": "100004686423103"
      },
      "name": "U.S.Navy D.E.P.",
      "description": "Was a pretty fun day. We were out there helping restore this World War 2 Destroyer.",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=178309025668644&id=100004686423103&aid=1073741835",
      "cover_photo": "178309055668641",
      "count": 4,
      "type": "normal",
      "created_time": "2013-06-10T00:32:45+0000",
      "updated_time": "2013-06-10T00:33:49+0000",
      "can_upload": false,
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "100000651398529",
            "name": "Jennifer Manuel Hyatt"
          },
          {
            "id": "1801948293",
            "name": "Calvin Carter"
          },
          {
            "id": "1522740127",
            "name": "Bliss Reane Kinder"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "after": "MTUyMjc0MDEyNw==",
            "before": "MTAwMDAwNjUxMzk4NTI5"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "150228468476700",
      "from": {
        "name": "James McMahon",
        "id": "100004686423103"
      },
      "name": "Untitled Album",
      "description": "03112013",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=150228468476700&id=100004686423103&aid=1073741830",
      "cover_photo": "150228475143366",
      "count": 1,
      "type": "normal",
      "created_time": "2013-03-15T05:27:54+0000",
      "updated_time": "2013-03-15T05:28:17+0000",
      "can_upload": false
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "MTUwMjI4NDY4NDc2NzAw",
      "before": "MTUwMjI4NzMxODEwMDA3"
    }
  }
}
Response received in 237 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `id` field- that's the **album-id**

So, you can create the link by yourself, just like this-

> `https://graph.facebook.com/<ALBUM-ID>/photos`

from this you can fetch all the photos of a particular album (but remember that you'll need the access token- of-course)

> `https://graph.facebook.com/<ALBUM-ID>/photos?access_token=<ACCESS-TOKEN>`

Comment: I believe the access token will be passed automatically through the sdk if im not mistaken, but this is what i was looking for.

Comment: Yes, if you are using SDK, access token will be passwd automatically